# How can I use Prometheus Histogram to get latency/response time of an application?

Tags: prometheus, latency, promql, response-time, kube-prometheus-stack

I deployed a web app and kube-prometheus-stack on a Kubernetes cluster, and I am trying to measure the latency of the application on Prometheus.

I see that I can get some results for the `prometheus_http_requests_total` query or `histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))` query. However, I get results for Prometheus but not for the application.

I am very new to Prometheus and PromQL, so I would appreciate any help to write a query to get latency/response time of the application.

Or is it possible to get the result with `sum(rate(container_http_request{container!=""}[5m])) by (namespace)`?

Comment: Because you're saying you're new, did you already take a look into the [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) for PromQL?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I get empty query results. So I thought I am missing smt that is not mentioned in that doc.